# How to accept their changes in git

Tags: javascript, git, visual-studio-code

I've done a

```
git pull <some_url>
```

And a lot of files become in merge conflict state.
How can i accept their changes using vscode or native git bash commands, without removing HEAD file by file?

Comment: I don't think this question has to be here.

Comment: Nonetheless, in order to get the remote origin changes : git reset --hard origin branch

Comment: If you want to stash (remove and save the local working directory changes) you can do : git stash.  Then to retrieve the changes : git stash pop

Comment: Resolve the conflicts and `commit`. FWIW, I prefer `fetch` and [`merge` or `rebase`] to `pull`, though. It gives you more explicit control. You can examine upstream changes before incorporating them into your local branch.

Comment: @Pomme De Terre, nothing "has to be here". Why do you think it shouldn't be?

Comment: The main problem here is the lack of knowledge about git from the writer. A simple search engine query would have answered with the different ways to achieve that depending the writer's need. Mine, yours, the accept answers will help him find a solution to this problem, but he will still have problems if he does not understand how git is working. He might loose work

Comment: @PommeDeTerre It doesn't the lack. It's a plenty of ways how to do it. I'd like to know how to do it with vscode. Therefore, i know how to perform it using git merge.

Comment: @MichaelDaineka sorry if I misunderstood

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, remember that `git pull` means:

1. Run `git fetch`.
2. If that succeeds, run a second Git command, typically `git merge`.

Both steps can fail, though typically step 1 usually succeeds and usually people get stuck in step 2.  **The way to get unstuck depends on which command you selected to use in step 2.**  So it's very important that you know which second command you had `git pull` run for you.  (This is one of many reasons I prefer to run each of the two commands separately, myself.)

You ran `git pull` and step 1 succeeded, then—I assume based on your question—step 2 actually ran `git merge`, and this is what failed.  So you're now in the *middle of a conflicted merge*.  **In a conflicted merge, several Git commands will refuse to do anything.**  You must exit this conflicted state first!  To do that, you have two options:

- *Finish* the merge.  That's the one you don't want, at this point, but let's mention how it's done:  To finish the merge you must resolve each conflicted file, then run `git merge --continue` or `git commit`.
- *Abort* the merge: run `git merge --abort`.  **This throws out any resolutions you have done so far!**

If you haven't done any work on resolving the merge, and just want to get out of the conflicted state, you can go ahead and use `git merge --abort`.  After doing that, there is no need to run `git pull` again.  It's just going to do the two steps—`fetch` and then second-command—and the `fetch` this time will have nothing to do.  So now you can run a `git merge` with options.

**The simple command to use at this point is `git merge -X theirs`.**  This uses your current branch's *upstream* setting—which `git pull` itself also used—to retry the merge, but this time with the `-X theirs` option.  You *can* run `git pull -X theirs`, and you can keep that in mind for future `git pull` commands, but I'd recommend avoiding `git pull`.  Run the two separate commands separately, even though this means typing in two commands instead of one.  That way you'll know for sure whether you're getting `git merge` or `git rebase`, and if and when the second command goes wrong, you'll know what to do—or at least what to *ask*—to get *out* of it.

Answer (score 2):

```
git pull -X theirs
```

See all the options: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull

Comment: `-X ours` will, in the conflicted sections, prefer the HEAD-side change: the opposite of what the OP asked for.